# Does PuTTY's SshHostKeys registry affect FileZilla in any way?

Tags: windows-registry, ftp, putty, sftp, filezilla

I deleted everything in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Simon Tatham/PuTTY/SshHostKeys`, and now FileZilla won't connect to one of my servers. (I'm using SFTP). Is there anyway to reset it? I have no idea why the two would be related but I was able to connect to the servers before removing those registry entities.

The server i'm trying to connect to is only accessible locally, so I'm using password auth. I'm not using an RSA key pair.

The output of filezilla is

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.5.75:1947...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "username@192.168.5.75" 1947
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**NOTE:** I have omitted the username in the third line intentionally. I have verified that the username is correct. But again, this started all of a sudden, without me changing any settings in FZ. Port number is correct as well. AND I can connect with PuTTY.

Here is the event log for PuTTY when I connect to the server in question. (The server that FileZilla suddenly refuses to connect to)

```
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Connecting to 192.168.5.75 port 1947
2017-06-09 09:58:46 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.69
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Using SSH protocol version 2
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Host key fingerprint is:
2017-06-09 09:58:46 ssh-ed25519 256 78:16:77:65:fd:4a:c2:3c:6e:f2:32:fd:16:25:9c:9b
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2017-06-09 09:58:46 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Sent password
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Access granted
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Opening session as main channel
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Opened main channel
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2017-06-09 09:58:52 Started a shell/command
```

I've also tried uninstalling FZ, restarting the PC, and reinstalling FZ. No avail. I tried restarting the ssh service on the server, and restarting the server altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way that can be due to the host keys. You do not even get connected, at that point no host keys are involved.

You simply have no connectivity to the server.

So, unless you can connect with any other SSH/SFTP client, you have a completely different problem that you ask about.

---

Note that you are obviously confused about the keys. The host key has nothing to do with authentication. Read my article on [SSH keys](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) to understand, what different keys in SSH do.

Comment: Hey, that was an accident on my part. I changed the ports on here back to 22 for privacy/security, but missed one (Thank you for removing that quote btw, and Thanks for pointing that out.) Also, this particular server isn't even using RSA keys. It's using password auth because it's only accessible locally. I'll edit the question to reflect that. Sorry!

Comment: Not confused about hostkeys, just a typo. HOWEVER, that artical is very well written! Kudos! haha. I can connect via PuTTY though. weird eh?

Comment: So show us PuTTY event log (right lick PuTTY window title).

Comment: Are these logs from the same client machine? If they are there are two possibilities: 1) FileZilla gets blocked by some application-specific rule of local firewall. 2) You actually have some typo in an IP address or port number and we cannot see that, as you are not showing us real numbers (we've seen before that you are redacting the logs). - I do not see any other explanation.

Comment: They are indeed from the same client machine. I'll triple check all the IPs and ports. Would you consider it safe to post the actual port that I'm using? if so I'll edit the OP to show all real data. The server IS only accessible locally so...

Comment: No problem about posting actual port number, if the server cannot be access from the Internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60191/discussion-between-native-coder-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: I checked the port and IP and they were perfect. So I tried using the HostName of the server in FZ and VOILA! Which is weird, Especially since i can connect using the IP in PuTTY?

Comment: So what IP address does the hostname resolve to? What does FileZilla log file show?

Comment: Status: Connecting to Charlotte:1947...
Status: Connected to 192.168.5.75 - I know, it's weird